# how to write UTF-8 (persian) characters in pdf export of dynamic reports?

Tags: java, pdf, character-encoding, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I'm trying to export a report to pdf format using dynamic reports but the persian characters do not appear in pdf file. but I don't have this problem in xls files or jasper viewer. i have tried this method but it doesn't work. what should i do?

```
public void toPdf(String path){
    JasperPdfExporterBuilder pdfExporter = new ExporterBuilders()
    .pdfExporter(path);
    pdfExporter.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    try {

        jasperReportBuilder.toPdf(pdfExporter);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        logger.error("failed to create PDF", e1);
    }
}
```

excel export :
[image: excel export]

jasper viewer :

[image: jasper viewer]

PDF export :
[image]

Comment: Are you using the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: I don't use jasper directly but i set fonts to both english and persian fonts using dynamic reports' StyleBuilder.setFontName(String) method. it changes the font in xls and jasper viewer but makes no difference in pdf!

Comment: Are you using the *jrxml* file? What is your code for adding fields in *Detail* band?

Comment: @AlexK no I don't use jrxml file. I use jasperReportBuilder.addColumn method from dynamic reports. i use SelectQuery from [squiggle sql](https://code.google.com/p/squiggle-sql/wiki/Tutorial) to set the dataSource jasperReportBuilder.setDataSource(selectQuery.toString(), JDBCConnection)

Comment: try this http://www.dailyfreecode.com/forum/problem-farsi-fonts-dynamic-text-20522.aspx

Comment: @dave thanks but not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it. You can follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582969/use-fileoutputstream-to-create-a-utf-8-pdf-file).
The devil is the way you handle fonts. Use [this tutorial](http://www.dynamicreports.org/documentation/fonts) and change your encoding in fonts.xml to `Identity-H` (it is case sensitive!)

Answer (score 0):

I am using dynamic jasper API and whenever the PDF file name i am exporting into Linux server it gets changed if it contains German umlauts character like ä even though i am taking encoding as UTF-8 or ISO-8859-14,ISO-8859-15,ISO-8859-1 etc.

changed ä to  Ã¤ in dynamic jasper API(JasperConcatenatedReportBuilder) while exporting the PDF.

Comment: problem solved .i am using 'Arial Unicode MS' font and added ARIALUNI.TTF ,fonts.xml file in class-path.    font.xml contains below code-                                                                                                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<fontFamilies>

   <fontFamily name="Arial Unicode MS">
  <normal>ARIALUNI.TTF</normal>
  <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
  <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
  <exportFonts>
  </exportFonts>
 </fontFamily> 
 
</fontFamilies>