# How to write an UTF-8 character in pdf file using java

Tags: gnostice-pdf-one

How to write an UTF-8 character in pdf file using java?

I use netbeans, the following is the code. What should I add to my code that can display in the output pdf file?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.*;

import com.gnostice.pdfone.*;
import com.gnostice.pdfone.encodings.PdfEncodings;
import com.gnostice.pdfone.fonts.PdfFont;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import java.awt.Font;

public class createpdf {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws PdfException, IOException, DocumentException {
        create_sample_doc1();
        get_pagecount_from_sample_doc1();
        write_to_sample_doc1();

        // NOTE: Requires Tahoma font file in the 
        // current directory
        write_to_sample_doc1_using_fonts();
    }

    static void create_sample_doc1() throws IOException, PdfException {
        // Create a PdfWriter instance
        PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.fileWriter("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\files\\sample_doc1.pdf");

        // Create a PdfDocument instance with the PdfWriter

        PdfDocument d = new PdfDocument(w);

        // Write some text on page 1
        d.writeText("السلام");

        // Set output file to be displayed after it is  
        // written to
        d.setOpenAfterSave(true);       

        // Write document to file
        d.write();

        // Close all I/O streams associated with the writer
        w.dispose();
    }

    static void get_pagecount_from_sample_doc1() throws IOException,
            PdfException {
        // Create a PdfReader instance
        PdfReader r = PdfReader.fileReader("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\files\\sample_doc1.pdf");

        // Create a PdfDocument instance with the reader
        PdfDocument d = new PdfDocument(r);

        // Get page count and display on console
        System.out.println(
                "Number of pages in sample_doc1.pdf is " +
                d.getPageCount());

        // Close all I/O streams associated with the reader
        r.dispose();
    }

    static void write_to_sample_doc1() throws IOException, PdfException {
        // Create a PdfReader instance



        PdfReader r = PdfReader.fileReader(
                               "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\files\\sample_doc1.pdf",   // read from
                               "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\files\\sample_doc2.pdf");  // write to
            System.out.println("AFNAAAN");

        // Create a PdfDocument instance with the reader
        PdfDocument d = new PdfDocument(r);

        // Write text at position (100, 100) on page 1 
        d.writeText("السلام", 
                    100,   // x-coordinate 
                    50);   // y-coordinate

        // Set output file to be displayed after it is  
        // written to
        d.setOpenAfterSave(true);

        // Write to output file
        d.write();

        // Close all I/O streams associated with the reader
        r.dispose();

    }

    static void write_to_sample_doc1_using_fonts() throws IOException, PdfException, DocumentException {
        // Create a PdfReader instance
        PdfReader r = PdfReader.fileReader(
                       "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\files\\sample_doc1.pdf",   // read from
                       "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\files\\sample_doc3.pdf");  // write to

        // Create a PdfDocument instance with the reader
        PdfDocument d = new PdfDocument(r);
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
bf.correctArabicAdvance();





        // Create font objects
         PdfFont fontArialItalic = PdfFont.create(
                 "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ArabicNaskhSSK.ttf",    // name of installed font
                PdfFont.ITALIC , 
                18, 
                PdfEncodings.UTF_16BE);

        PdfFont fontTahomaNormal = PdfFont.create(
                "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ArabicNaskhSSK.ttf", // pathname of a font file
                PdfFont.STROKE_AND_FILL, 
                48, 
                PdfEncodings.UTF_16BE); 

        // Write text on page 1 using the Arial font created above 
        d.writeText("السلام", 
                    fontArialItalic,  // font
                    100, 50);

        // Set font properties
        fontTahomaNormal.setStrokeWidth(2);
        fontTahomaNormal.setStrokeColor(Color.RED);
        fontTahomaNormal.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

        // Write more text on page 1 using Tahoma
        d.writeText("السلام", 
                    fontTahomaNormal,  // font
                    100, 100);
            System.out.println("AFNAAAN5");

        // Set output file to be displayed after it is  
        // written to
        d.setOpenAfterSave(true);

        // Write to output file
        d.write();

        // Close all I/O streams associated with the reader
        r.dispose();
    }

}
```

I think I have to use utf-8 somewhere but I don't now where!
Please help.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "UTF-8 character"; UTF-8 is a character coding.

Comment: i got it , but I need to write Arabic character that need to write in pdf file

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you have the correct encoding selected for your source file in Netbeans?

Comment: You are really asking a question about the particular PDF-writing library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

According the [API of Gnotice PDFOne](http://www.gnostice.com/docs/pdfone_for_java/com/gnostice/pdfone/PdfDocument.html#writeText(java.lang.String,%20com.gnostice.pdfone.fonts.PdfFont)): you must use :

```
pdfDocument.write("someText", aFont)
```

where `aFont` can be created with [this factory method](http://www.gnostice.com/docs/pdfone_for_java/com/gnostice/pdfone/fonts/PdfFont.html#create(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)):

```
PdfFont.create(name, size, encoding)
```

where `encoding` is an int representing one of the supported [PdfEncodings](http://www.gnostice.com/docs/pdfone_for_java/com/gnostice/pdfone/encodings/PdfEncodings.html)

Unfortunately, UTF-8 is **not supported** by this library. I guess you will have to use another encoding (like UTF-16)... or another library.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a commercial software library,  [Gnostice PDFOne](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFOne_Java.asp), tt. o create a PDF. Apparently, it has a problem, limitation, complexity, with Arabic text. You would probably do better asking their tech support for advice, presumably paying them for a licenses entitles you to some of that. UTF-8 as nothing to do with it; their API apparently accepts full Java String values, so it is up to them to encode them correctly in the PDF file.

Answer (score -1):

you can use from this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582969/use-fileoutputstream-to-create-a-utf-8-pdf-file)

you have to change your default font, because the default font can't write utf8. I hope my text is usefull.